# Choosing from a collection of 2 classes of identical objects.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

In a bag there are w white balls and b black ball. In how many distinct ways one can choose k balls, without replacement, from this bag.
Also, In how many distinct ways one can choose k balls, such that ith ball is white.

Answer (score 3):

We can use binomial coefficients.

There are ${ {w + b} \choose k}$ way to choose balls without replacement.

The ith ball being white is by symmetry the same as the first ball being white. So
${ {w + b - 1} \choose {k-1}}$ ways.